# Hash String in Python

Tags: python

I'm working with a data set which has a users social security # (without the dashes) that I want to use as a unique id, but would like to hash (md5) the string in order to protect the identity of the user.  Here is a sample of the data set:

```
 id        |     date     |     sale_id
 543875600    2014-03-22        a4395
```

would like the output to look like this or similar:

```
 id                               |     date     |     sale_id
 762be25b5c6eb20dd6c791840c01aa33    2014-03-22        a4395
```

I would like to use python to solve as I'm currently using python with the data to aggregate many files within a directory, so this would be additional code which I would include in the following code:

```
 import glob
 files = glob.glob( '*.csv' )
 output="combined.csv"

 with open(output, 'w' ) as result:
      for thefile in files:
          f = [open(thefile).read()]
          for line in f:
              result.write( line )
  message = 'file created'
  print (message)
```

Comment: Hash it instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Maybe it will be better to use some hash function to protect identity of user.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: MD5 is insecure! Use some newer hash!
See: http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat

Comment: Try and go with SHA-256 or SHA-512 for the hashing algorithm. They are considered secure (for now). MD5 is definitely not a good choice. Both are included in hashlib

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> id = "000000000"
>>> my_hash = hashlib.sha224(id).hexdigest()
>>> my_hash
'c34c462b2fb1982287dc9df575c03669b308301dbc3be6d62dd83536'
```

Of course you could md5 if you really require it, or [any other hash function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) in the library.

Answer (score 0):

The technical answer first...

Reverse a string - the readable way:

```
>>> s = "abcde"
>>> "".join(reversed(s))
'edcba'
```

Reverse a string - the less readable way:

```
>>> s = "abcde"
>>> s[::-1]
'edcba'
```

"Scramble" a string:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = list(s)
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> "".join(l)
'dacbe'
```

Now Chris Arena and Zlopez are right: neither are a valid "protection", you really want to hash your ids instead.